# Admin changes not reflecting after migrating magento 1.9 to magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, configuration, migration, save

I have migrated my magento 1 site to magento 2.2.X by using  the
[migration tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool)

after done product and configuration all are migrated but when i change anything in admin like product qty or system configuration any thing change not reflecting but success message is showing any idea how to resolve pls help me

I have done cache clear ,indexing, di, and content deploy

Comment: try with cache clean once.

Comment: i have done all ways

Comment: did you check into database, value is being updated or not ?

Comment: not updating any changes